# C# Ubuntu 16.04 ошибка сборки

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu

При попытке запуска командой dotnet run возникает следующая ошибка

`/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(52,5): error MSB3105: The item "Program.cs" was specified more than once in the "Sources" parameter.  Duplicate items are not supported by the "Sources" parameter. [/home/ruben/myApp/myApp.csproj]`

Версия dotnet 2.1.302

Как решить данную проблему?

Содержимое myApp.csproj, какое тут идет дублирование?

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: `Duplicate items are not supported by the "Sources" parameter` убрать дублирование видимо

Comment: @tym32167 в этом файле дублирования я не вижу

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/604 ©Remove all "Compile" elements from your `.csproj` and let the SDK add all `.cs` files to your project automatical. If you want to control which files are added and don't want the SDK to automatically added them, set `<EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>` property in your `.csproj`.

Comment: C# на Ubuntu? Вы это серьёзно?

Comment: @IgorKudryashov а что такого?

Comment: Возьмите Windows вместо Ubuntu или Java вместо C#. По-моему все эти поползновения Microsoft в сторону Linux пока только на стадии научных экспериментов. Пользоваться этим надо с осторожностью, оглядкой и пониманием, что нормально оно у вас не заработает.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov это предрассудки. Mono уже давно работает на Linux, asp.net core проекты уже не первый год запускают под линукс, сам сейчас пилю домашний проект на asp.net core + сборки на .net standard (которые ещё и шарятся с другими .net проектами для декстопа на винде) - пока полет нормальный.